# How to configure my django project: Template Does Not Exist Error?

Tags: python, html, django, debugging, http-status-code-500

I am new to the Django framework trying to work through a youtube tutorial to better understand. I created a simple blog post webiste, which was working correctly until I attempted to update my urls.py, views.py, and home.html files respectively. Now when I go to to test the URL on my local machine I am returned with a 500 internal server error, which I do not understand. To my belief my project was configured correctly as I had configured all the variables on my settings.py file. I've added my blog name to the

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '**DrewThe1stBlog**',
```

], ROOT_URLCONF = '**DrewsBlog.urls**':url config
Can anyone provide any insight to what I have done wrong.

I have tried to debug the code but I am unable to understand the stack trace. Some simple research on Stack Overflow I have tried adding my python path to the the Templates_DIR amongst other things which have not worked.

StackTrace below:

> 

```
Environment:
> 
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
> 
> Django Version: 4.1.7
> Python Version: 3.8.5
> Installed Applications:
> ['django.contrib.admin',
>  'django.contrib.auth',
>  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>  'django.contrib.sessions',
>  'django.contrib.messages',
>  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>  'DrewThe1stBlog']
> Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
> 
> Template loader postmortem
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
> 
> Using engine django:
> django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/DrewsBlog/DrewThe1stBlog/templates/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/DrewsBlog/DrewThe1stBlog/templates/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
> 
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
> response = response.render()
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
> self.content = self.rendered_content
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 90, in rendered_content
> template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 72, in resolve_template
> return select_template(template, using=self.using)
> File "/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
> raise TemplateDoesNotExist(", ".join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
> 
> Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
> Exception Value: DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html
>
```

See attached for screenshots of my python files

[Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtuWV.png)[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPnc.png)[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OETPp.png)[home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI2ca.png)

Comment: template_name instead of templateName in your view

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error, which means that Django cannot find the template file that you're trying to use in your views.py file. According to the stack trace you provided, the template file that's missing is DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html.

Here are a few things that you can check to resolve this error:

1. Make sure that the TEMPLATES setting in your settings.py file is configured correctly. This setting should include a list of template engines that Django should use to render templates, as well as a list of template directories where Django should look for template files. Here's an example:

```js
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This example sets the DIRS option to include a directory called 'templates' that's located in the project's base directory. If your template file is located in a different directory, you'll need to add that directory to the DIRS list.

2. Make sure that the template file exists in the correct location. In the stack trace you provided, Django is looking for the template file at `/Users/drewcampbell/PersonalWebsitePython/DrewsBlog/DrewThe1stBlog/templates/DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html`, but it's not finding it. Double-check that the file exists at that location and that the filename is spelled correctly.
3. Make sure that you're passing the correct template name to the render method in your views.py file. In your get method, you should have a line that looks like this:

```js
return render(request, 'DrewThe1stBlog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Make sure that the first argument to the render method is the correct name of your template file.

Hopefully one of these suggestions will help you resolve the "TemplateDoesNotExist" error that you're seeing.

Comment: Your 8 most recent answers all appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.